# Allowing user to make charge against saved credit card?

Tags: ios

Our company is a subscription based service with an iPhone/iPad app that allows our customers mobile access to our service (and agriculture database). We are thinking of adding a new product that we will need to charge the customer per use.

I'm wondering if we allow customers to save their credit card to our server (following what ever rules Authorize.Net requires) so they can authorize us to make a charge against the card through the app? i believe we would require the user to enter some data to confirm their identity (such as CID or last 4 digits of card).

Would this violate apple's in-app purchase policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Section 11.2 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty much going to violate Apple's in app purchase policy. Check Apple's app store review guidelines section 11.